# Missing flags for screen capture in recent Chrome Update

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, screen-capture, getusermedia

I was till last month using Chrome Browser for testing the screen share feature using WebRTC API. For doing this I enabled the flag "Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia()" in chrome://flags.

Now with recent update of the Chrome Browser, this flag is no more available and most of the other WebRTC flags are disabled. I checked with even Chrome Canary and the result was same. The flags are either missing or disabled with message "Sorry, this experiment is not available on your platform.".

I am neither able to revert to older chrome version.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a clue as to how enable the above flag for screen capture?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Canary - on Macbook Air OSX 10.9.4 is giving error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763088/google-canary-on-macbook-air-osx-10-9-4-is-giving-error)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use those flags any longer and there is NO WAY to access them again short of rolling back your update. They were removed for security reasons. Now, you have to use a chrome plugin to do any desktop capture. Which is frustrating but the only way and it is fairly simple.

Here is an [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763088/google-canary-on-macbook-air-osx-10-9-4-is-giving-error/25765927#25765927) that should give you direction.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox also now has screen/window/etc capture.  For now, for similar reasons to Chrome, we've put access to the feature behind a whitelist (though an extension could extend the whitelist as well; we haven't prototyped that yet).

See http://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html (In Firefox 33 or later - currently that's Beta; no attempt to polyfill was done there as it's an internal testing page).