# Desktop Capture with Audio

Tags: javascript, audio, video, web, webrtc

I am working on a web application that captures a users screen and sends the screen to another user.  So far I have the desktop capture working great and I used peer.js for this.  Now I would like to add audio from the users microphone to the stream as well.  So I thought it would be as simple as to set the audio variable to true in the getUserMedia call but that just leaves me with an error.  Any ideas?

```
function startScreenStreamFrom(streamId) {
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
   audio: true,
   video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
        maxWidth: window.screen.width,
        maxHeight: window.screen.height
                 }
         }
},

function(screenStream) {
  stream = screenStream;
  videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(screenStream);
  videoElement.play();
  videoplaying = true;
  broadcaststarted = true;
},

function(error) {
  console.log('getUserMedia failed!: ' + error);
});
}
```

This brings up the Navigate User Media Error.

Comment: You have a microphone connected correct and webrtc is able to access it?

Comment: Yes there is a microphone connected, but how would I know if webrtc is able to access it?

Comment: You could just do a request for the microphone alone and see if you can get the stream.

Comment: how would I request for the microphone?  I thought once the audio was set to true that it automatically requested for the microphone.

Comment: It does, but do so for it ALONE, to determine if your microphone is the problem. Also, Chrome has updated how they access the desktop and it has to be done through a plugin. This SO question may give direction on desktop capture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763088/google-canary-on-macbook-air-osx-10-9-4-is-giving-error/25765927#25765927

Comment: I can successfully access the microphone.  Also I know I have to access the desktop through an extension and that is not the problem.  I can already successfully share the screen with another user.  The problem is when I try to share audio and the screen at the same time.  I can share both of them individually and it works fine.  As soon as I try them both I get the error.  Can you not share the desktop and audio in the same stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you cannot share the screen and audio at the same time.  One way to solve this would be to have two separate streams and load the video stream in a video element and the audio in a seperate audio element.  Or if you wish you can load them both to the video element.

Comment: Hi Collin, can you please share solution or steps/settings for navigation.GetUserMedia? I know it has been over an year but I can definately try your solution.