# What JavaScript API to Use to Launch Apps in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

How can I check within my own app which other apps are installed on Chrome OS?

Can I start a third party app from my own app in JavaScript? Or even from my Android App running in ARC?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The question is aimed at the necessary JavaScript API. To reflect this I reworded the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120647/546411). 
Looks to be part of what you are trying to do. Then you can probably leverage the [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API to get the list of applications installed.